# WCF Service Timeout from Classic ASP

Tags: wcf, asp-classic

We are seeing random timeout issue when trying to invoke WCF Service through Classic ASP(VBScript). I verified WCF trace but don't see any error or warning. What is best way to debug the issue? We are using JSON response format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your configuration values to see what the timeout is supposed to be, and that the client and server timeouts match.

Then check the server side logs so that you see if the responses are taking as long as the timeout.

Try to find a pattern:

- Time of day
- After a recycling
- Heavy load
- Number of clients / connections.

90% of the time I see this problem it is due to the WCF clients not being closed. The problem is that by default there are 10 WCF connections, they are used untill they get closed. So the first 10 go fast, the 11th must wait for one of the others to be available. This will be when it is closed or timesout.

Comment: Thanks Shiraz! I see error happening whenever there is considerable load on server. We are using classic ASP as WCF Client so I am not sure how can we close the connection using that.